# Stored struct member data via char array pointer return garbage value

Tags: mysql, c, pointers, struct, arduino-esp8266

I am trying to display my [database data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uV0Gk.png) on an OLED LCD using `MySQL_Connection.h` and `MySQL_Cursor.h` by `ChuckBell`.

The link to this library is https://github.com/ChuckBell/MySQL_Connector_Arduino>

I was able to fetch data from `mysql database` successfully. However, I wish to store the data in a char array so that I can later display them on the OLED LCD. The problem is the value stored always returns garbage value. I know its something to do with char array pointer but after searching for so long, I still couldn't find the correct syntax. Below is the snippet of my code.

Start by setting up Wifi connection and mysql connection.

```
#include <MySQL_Connection.h>
#include <MySQL_Cursor.h>
char query[] = "SELECT * FROM test.assetdemo WHERE RFID = \"048EB25A\"";  //sql query
char* sqldata[11];               //array of char pointer to store the 11 data in the database 

void setup(){
    Serial.begin(115200);
    internetConnect(ssid,pw);                             //connect to Wifi
    conn.connect(server_addr, 3306, user, password);      //connect to mysqldatabase
}
```

Then begin looping function to store and display the database data.

```
void loop(){
    Serial.println("\nRunning SELECT and printing results\n");

    MySQL_Cursor *cur_mem = new MySQL_Cursor(&conn);   // Initiate the query class instance
    cur_mem->execute(query);                           // Execute the query

    row_values *row = NULL;                            // Read the rows and print them
    do {
        row = cur_mem->get_next_row();
        if (row != NULL) {
            for (int f = 0; f < cols->num_fields; f++) {
                sqldata[f] = row->values[f];
                Serial.print(f);
                Serial.print("    ");
                Serial.println(sqldata[f]);    /*This works*/
              }
            Serial.println();
          }
     } while (row != NULL);
     Serial.println(sqldata[0]);      /*This return garbage value*/
     delete cur_mem;                   // frees up memory used  
     delay(5000);
}
```

The output is shown as below [Click here or view below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nETAA.png). As you can see, the values are displayed correctly (except 8th which is of boolean type which i will change it later) in the `do while` loop. However, when I exit the loop and print the value again, it returns garbage value `⸮`. `sqldata[0]` supposes to return `048EB25A`.

```
Running SELECT and printing results


0    048EB25A
1    Blood Pressure Monitor
2    NA
3    WelchAllyn 503-0054-03
4    010720
5    NA
6    NA
7    Blood Pressure Cuff
8    
9    Yes
10    1

⸮
```

The code snippet below shows the struct declaration in `MySQL_Cursor.h`

```
typedef struct {
  char *db;
  char *table;
  char *name;
} field_struct;

// Structure for storing result set metadata.
typedef struct {
  int num_fields;     // actual number of fields
  field_struct *fields[MAX_FIELDS];
} column_names;

// Structure for storing row data.
typedef struct {
  char *values[MAX_FIELDS];
} row_values;
```

Part of me knew that **`sqldata[f] = row->values[f];`** is causing the garbage value. The value will change as the pointer only points to the address. How can I store the variable statically so that after the `do while`, the value will persist?
Kind sirs and madams please explain this mystery.

PS: I am confused at array and pointer, even more when they involve struct.

Comment: Try changing "char* sqldata[11]"  as "static char* sqldata[11]" and see.

Comment: Probbaly `row = cur_mem->get_next_row();` invalidates the memory filled by the previous `row = cur_mem->get_next_row();`. Don't copy the pointers but copy the strings.

Comment: @user846834 that doesn't work =( Still return garbage value.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Thanks for the advice. After searching for a long time, I finally able to store the strings instead of the pointers. Will update the solution later. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Don't put an answer into the question and don't put "[SOLVE]" into the title. This site isn't a forum.

Comment: @gre_gor Oh just read FAQ and found out about the rules of posting question. Thanks for the reminder ya. Will remove the answer.

Comment: You can add it as a new answer, if it adds anything to the existing answer.

Comment: Yup just did it. Thanks again for the reminder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the solution myself thanks to the advices given by @Jabberwocky and @rantan pan. They provided me a direction on where to look for the solution.
By editting `sqldata` as shown below, I was able to store the strings instead of pointer into sqldata.

Re-declare sqldata as shown below.

```
char **sqldata = new char*[11];     //to store 11 data for each query executed
for ( int i = 0; i < 11; i++ )
{
    sqldata[i] = new char[11];
}
```

Then replace `sqldata[f] = row->values[f];` with `strcpy(sqldata[f], (*row).values[f]);`

All is working right now. Time to print this crap on an OLED LCD. 
Thanks again folks!

Answer (score 2):

The explanation is that the memory is freed inside get_next_row function https://github.com/ChuckBell/MySQL_Connector_Arduino/blob/master/src/MySQL_Cursor.cpp

```
/*
  get_next_row - Iterator for reading rows from a result set
  This method returns an instance of a structure (row_values)
  that contains an array of strings representing the row
  values returned from the server.
  The caller can use the values however needed - by first
  converting them to a specific type or as a string.
*/
row_values *MySQL_Cursor::get_next_row() {
  int res = 0;

  free_row_buffer();

  // Read the rows
  res = get_row_values();
  if (res != MYSQL_EOF_PACKET) {
    return &row;
  }
  return NULL;
}
```

At the second attempt to get rows **free_row_buffer** is called.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the free_row_buffer. Guess I had to figure out how to store the values before the free_row_buffer() is called. Anyway thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Solution from @TK Ooi is ok, but as an improvement to it I would go safer with the size of the array where we want to store the data, and thus can be done instead of using

```
int numberRows = 11;
char **sqldata = new char*[numberRows];
for(int i = 0; i < numberRows; i++ ) {
    sqldata[i] = new char[numberChars];
}
strcpy(sqldata[f], (*row).values[f]);`
```

better declaring your array of char* as global but doing inside your query function the following:

```
int numberChars = strlen((*row).values[f]);
sqldata[f] = new char[numberChars]; // implies already extra place for null terminator
snprintf(sqldata[f], strlen(sqldata[f]), "%s", (*row).values[f]);`
```

This way, we are assigning always the exact length to our array to store the recovered data. Note that using `numberChars` instead of `strlen(sqldata[f])` will fail because you need to pass the length according to the type stored in `sqldata`: it's not the same for `int` as for `char`...